Замена цвета секторов в Колесе фортуны на JPG изображения
Всем привет!
Наткнулся на просторах гугла на статью по созданию “колеса фортуны”. Собственно сама статья.
Вроде сверстал и все работает, но ломаю голову как заменить в каждом секторе заливку цветом на изображение формата .jpg. Есть у кого опыт реализации такой идеи?
Для удобства перенёс код на codepen


Ну вот же у вас есть функция, которая отвечает за рисование секторов и их цвета
// рисуем разноцветные секторы
const createConicGradient = () => {
  // устанавливаем нужное значение стиля у элемента spinner
  spinner.setAttribute(
    "style",
    `background: conic-gradient(
      from -90deg,
      ${prizes
        // получаем цвет текущего сектора
        .map(({ color }, i) => `${color} 0 ${(100 / prizes.length) * (prizes.length - i)}%`)
        .reverse()
      }
    );`
  );
};

Но ее проблема в том, что она рисует все колесо в целом, а не сектора поотдельности. По этому можно вставить лишь одно общее изображние на колесо.
Чтобы вставить изображение на каждый призовой отсек, это нужно менять подход к созданию этих секторов.
Другой вариант состоит в том, у вас есть элементы с классом prize, как раз на каждом секторе. Вы можете помграться с ними так, чтобы их форма совпадала с формой треугольника, которую видит пользователь, а затем просто добавить к каждому элементу свой соответствующий background.
Суть в том, что текущая реализация совсем не рассчитана чтобы там были изображения вместо секторов, надо многое модифицировать или вообще полностью переписывать подход к рисованию колеса и призовых секторов.
